# How can I get DFP creative setting data by Id via the googletag object?

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

In DFP I can manage attributes for each creative; type, name, destination url, etc.

[image]

And in the following JavaScript, I receive `ad_data` which contains data about the DFP ad which has completed rendering on the page. Part of this data includes `creativeId` which matches the Id shown while managing the creative in DFP.

```
googletag.cmd.push( function() {
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener( 'slotRenderEnded', function( ad_data ) {
        console.log( ad_data );
    } );
} );
```

[image]

Is there a way to get the creative setting data using this id? I'm not seeing anything in the [GPT Reference](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference) or searching around online. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe! It depends on what you're trying to get...

```js
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
        if (event.isEmpty) return;

        console.log(event.size);

        var isNativeContentAd = event.slot.getSizes().some(size => size ==='fluid');
        console.log(isNativeContentAd);

        // creativeId...
        console.log(event.creativeId);
        // or
        console.log(event.sourceAgnosticCreativeId);

        // this is the #id of the div you mounted the ad in...
        console.log(event.slot.getSlotElementId());

        // adsense attributes; get them individually with `event.slot.get('key')`
        console.log(event.slot.getAttributeKeys());

        // when in doubt, have a look in:
        console.log(event.slot.getHtml());
    });
});
```

I can't see any way of getting the alt text, other than inspecting `event.slot.getHtml()`. For a simple creative of type 'image', I found the alt text was in:

```
#google_image_div > a#aw0 > img.img_ad
```

### [slotRendeRendedEvent](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsslotrenderendedevent):

> - `advertiserId` Advertiser ID of the rendered ad.
> - `campaignId` Campaign ID of the rendered ad.
> - `creativeId` Creative ID of the rendered reservation ad.
> - `isEmpty` true if no ad was returned for the slot, false otherwise.
> - `lineItemId` Line item ID of the rendered reservation ad.
> - `size` Indicates the pixel size of the rendered creative.
> - `sourceAgnosticCreativeId` Creative ID of the rendered reservation or backfill ad.
> - `sourceAgnosticLineItemId` Line item ID of the rendered reservation or backfill ad.

### [googletag.Slot](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletagslot):

> - `addService(service)` Adds a service to this slot.
> - `clearCategoryExclusions()` Clears all slot-level ad category exclusion labels for this slot.
> - `clearTargeting(opt_key)` Clears specific or all custom slot-level targeting parameters for this slot.
> - `defineSizeMapping(sizeMapping)` Sets an array of mappings from a minimum viewport size to slot size for this slot.
> - `get(key)` Returns the value for the AdSense attribute associated with the given key.
> - `getAdUnitPath()` Returns the full path of the ad unit, with the network code and ad unit path.
> - `getAttributeKeys()` Returns the list of attribute keys set on this slot.
> - `getCategoryExclusions()` Returns the ad category exclusion labels for this slot.
> - `getResponseInformation()` Returns the ad response information.
> - `getSlotElementId()` Returns the id of the slot element provided when the slot was defined.
> - `getTargeting(key)` Returns a specific custom targeting parameter set on this slot.
> - `getTargetingKeys()` Returns the list of all custom targeting keys set on this slot.

[adsense_attributes](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/adsense_attributes) may be relevant to you, too.

Note that the fields available may also depend on the network delivering the ad - eg if the creative is being served by a prebid partner.